# Why is a FastCGI HHVM hanging on larger data sets?

Tags: php, hhvm

I have written a small benchmarking suite that includes CLI tests for PHP, HHVM and Zephir. I am now attempting to add FastCGI tests for PHP, HHVM and Zephir. For context you can see the [article I originally wrote](http://simonholywell.com/post/2014/02/hhvm-vs-zephir-vs-php-the-showdown.html) to accompany this.

The [code is available](https://github.com/treffynnon/Benchmark-PHP-HHVM-Zephir/tree/fcgi) in the fcgi branch on GitHub.

Essentially I have created a HHVM extension, PHP and Hack version of the same Mandelbrot set generating code (see `fcgi-hhvm-*` on GitHub project). For each of them I setup (`setup.sh`) a HHVM FastCGI server, warm it up by making a few requests against it and then benchmark. The FastCGI request is handled by a C++ FastCGI CLI client to make it's footprint on the benchmark as minimal as possible rather than say nginx.

It works fine with Mandelbrot sets of 100x100 and 200x200, but as soon as it is ramped up to 1,000 it randomly hangs during one of the iterations for HHVM running PHP, Hack or via the HHVM extension.

Unfortunately nothing is written to the logs either and it just silently hangs. If I kill the job and try to re-run it without stopping and starting the server it hangs again. So it is leaving the server in a failed state, but not causing the server to crash or die.

I have tried changing a number of config options - see the related issue on my project: https://github.com/treffynnon/Benchmark-PHP-HHVM-Zephir/issues/7

Does anyone know if there is a setting I should be tweaking or an issue that could be causing this problem?

Incidentally the PHP scripts take longer to run, but they complete successfully every time so I am pretty sure it isn't something in my client implementation, but something in HHVM itself. The same test runs fine via HHVM on the CLI, but not via FastCGI.

HHVM version: built from master@190a12a

Comment: It would probably be extremely helpful to specify the HHVM version you're using.

Comment: @RaduMurzea I thought I had - edited. I have since lodged a ticket against the project too: https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/issues/2028

Comment: You did, but in your article and it would've been hard to find for someone interested in your question. I'm very interested in HHVM, please don't forget to let us know via an answer/comment/edit how this issue was resolved (if it was).

Comment: Could you try switching on authoritative mode and see if it still hangs?